# Property 'ItemID' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'

Tags: javascript, angular, .net-core

I know this is a repeated question, but I couldn't find the solution for my problem.

services.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemDetailService {

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private http:HttpClient) { }
  readonly BaseURL='http://localhost:47522/api/';
  itemModel = this.fb.group({
    ItemID: [''],
    ItemName: [''],
    ItemPrice: ['']
  });

  postItemDetails(){
    var itemData = {
      ItemID: this.itemModel.value.ItemID,
      ItemName: this.itemModel.value.ItemName,
      ItemPrice: this.itemModel.value.ItemPrice
    };

    return this.http.post(this.BaseURL + '/Item/AddItem', itemData);
  }
}
```

componet.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemDetailService } from 'src/app/shared/item-detail.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-detail',
  templateUrl: './item-detail.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:ItemDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.itemModel.reset();
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    
    //alert('clicked');
    this.service.postItemDetails().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.service.itemModel.reset();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

html file

```
<form  #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <input type="hidden" name="ItemID" [value]="service.itemModel.ItemID">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="ItemName" #ItemName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.itemModel.ItemName" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Item Name" required minlength="3" maxlength="25">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="ItemPrice" #ItemPrice="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.itemModel.ItemPrice" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Item Price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" required type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid"><i
                class="fas fa-database"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

These are my files. When I  debug my API, the values returning is null. And the console keeps showing me the error Property 'ItemID' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing model driven forms (form defined with the formBuilder) and template driven forms (changing the value with ngModel). You should focus of one of the solutions as explained in the official documentation.

About your error, you can't just access the value of a control of a FormGroup by using *service.itemModel.ItemId*.

You should either change your formGroup into a basic object to be able to change its value with *ngModel* or add reactive forms directives inside your template to manage your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemDetailService {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) { }
  readonly BaseURL = 'http://localhost:47522/api/';
  initForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      ItemID: [''],
      ItemName: [''],
      ItemPrice: ['']
    });
  }

  postItemDetails(itemData) {
    return this.http.post(this.BaseURL + '/Item/AddItem', itemData);
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemDetailService } from './item.service';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
itemForm: FormGroup;
 constructor(private service:ItemDetailService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemForm = this.service.initForm();
  }

  onSubmit(){
    
    //alert('clicked');
       this.itemForm.reset();
    this.service.postItemDetails(this.itemForm.value).subscribe(
      res => {
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<form  [formGroup]="itemForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="hidden" name="ItemID" formControlName="ItemID">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="ItemName" formControlName="ItemName"  class="form-control"
            placeholder="Item Name" required minlength="3" maxlength="25">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="ItemPrice"  formControlName="ItemPrice"  class="form-control"
            placeholder="Item Price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="itemForm.invalid"><i
                class="fas fa-database"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Here is stackblitz working demo for more details  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wmbeqe